# CLLocation object in swift with latitude and longitude

Tags: objective-c, swift, cllocation

I would try to set the latitude and the longitude property of a `CLLocation` object but I get this error on running:

> Cannot convert CLlocation object to EMTrackPoint Object

[image]

```
for element in objectsArray {
    let item = CLLocation(latitude: element.latitude, longitude: element.longitude) as! EMTrackPoint

    item.mElevation = element.ele
    item.mOrientation = element.orientation
    item.mDate = Date()
    if element.poiActive != ""{
         GPXActive.add(element.poiActive.components(separatedBy: ","))
    }
    GPXDanger.add(element.dangerActive.components(separatedBy: ","))
    item.mActivePOIs = GPXActive
    item.mActiveDangers = GPXDanger
    GPXPoints.add(item)
}
```

The `EMTrackPoint` class in Objective C:

```
@interface EMTrackPoint : CLLocation

@property (nonatomic, assign) double mElevation;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *mDate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *mActivePOIs;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *mActiveDangers;
@property (nonatomic, assign) double mOrientation;
@property (nonatomic, assign) double mSpeed;
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `EMTrackPoint` is also a `CLLocation` so why don't you initialize a `EMTrackPoint` instance in the first place instead of doing the typecasting:

```
for element in objectsArray {
    let item = EMTrackPoint(latitude: element.latitude, longitude: element.longitude)
    item.mElevation = element.ele
    item.mOrientation = element.orientation
    item.mDate = Date()
    ...
```